# "Let's go ahead" when talking about passing people on the street

Tags: word-usage

My whole class was walking in two rows. My friend and I were walking together. So she wanted to pass the two kids walking in front of us, and walk in front of them because they were way too slow:

> Come on, let's go ahead.
>
> Come on, let's get ahead.

Do they sound natural and likely? And what about "let's move up" or something similar?

Comment: Let's pass them, is what we say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Let's go ahead" sounds OK, although usually wouldn't be used to imply passing people - "let's go ahead" just implies the general direction (it's often used when we're stationary, and then decide to "go ahead").

"Let's get ahead" you'd be unlikely to hear without clarification.

In this context you'd most likely hear:

> - Let's get past these two.
> - Let's get ahead of these two.
> - Let's go ahead of these two.
> - Let's go past these two.

Comment: Is. "get ahead of these two" likely to be heard, or "let's get past them" sounds more likely?(and better)

Comment: Yes, "get past" is more likely. To me, "get ahead" of them sort of implies that we are walking together in a sense, even though we are not directly aligned, as though we are part of the same group, or procession, or maybe a queue, or something like that.

Comment: And does this work: "Let's go around them."

Comment: So "go ahead of" is more likey when people are walking in a group, and not exactly in parallel lines, right?

Comment: "Go around", to me, sounds more like the thing you are going around is stationary (not moving).

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel lines"? I wouldn't say "go ahead" was strictly reserved for walking in a group.